# calculate the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{t^{z-1}\cos(t)}{e^{t}-1} dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I am trying to calculate the integral $$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{t^{z-1}\cos(t)}{e^{t}-1} dt$$

Comment: CAS says if $z>1$ answer is: $\frac{1}{2} (\zeta (z,1-i)+\zeta (z,1+i)) \Gamma (z)$.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Using the identity $\frac{1}{e^t-1}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-k t}$, from the Mellin Transform $\mathcal{M}_t\left[e^{-k t} \cos (t)\right](z)=\Gamma (z) \frac{\cos\left(z \cot^{-1}(k)\right)}{\left(k^2+1\right)^{z/2}}$ I get $\Gamma(z) \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos\left(z \cot^{-1}(k)\right)}{\left(k^2+1\right)^{z/2}}$ which I believe is valid for $\Re(z)>1$ and perhaps equivalent to the result you posted for $\Re(z)>1$.